# Simulated file drop and upload in dropzone.js

Tags: javascript, file-upload, dropzone.js

I'm writing a test harness for a web page containing a dropzone.js element, let's call it `myDropzone`, represented by the `$('#my-dropzone')` element.

Question:

**Can I use javascript to simulate dropping an uploadable file onto the dropzone?**

I think (but I'm not sure) this might entail something like:

1. Creating a file-like object in javascript, then
2. Triggering a drop event on `myDropzone`.

Step #2 is easy, but step #1 involves creating a file-like object (containing  real datastream?) that can actually be uploaded once it is dropped.

I've tried creating dummy files such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17582713/programatically-add-existing-file-to-dropzone) and then using `myDropzone.addFile(...)`, but that doesn't result in an uploadable file because there is no data payload.

thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What I was able to do was create a Blob file from a base64 encoded file (image in this case) and pass that to addFile(), so it essentially is simulating dropping a file.

```
dropZone.addFile(base64toBlob(base64FileData, 'image/png'));
```

Where `base64toBlob` is:

```
function base64toBlob(b64Data, contentType, sliceSize) {
    contentType = contentType || '';
    sliceSize = sliceSize || 512;

    var byteCharacters = atob(b64Data);
    var byteArrays = [];

    for (var offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize) {
        var slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);

        var byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
        for (var i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
            byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
        }

        var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);

        byteArrays.push(byteArray);
    }

    var blob = new Blob(byteArrays, {type: contentType});
    return blob;
}
```

**Full Demo http://jsfiddle.net/P2dTF/52/**